# Ways to create a VS 2013 C# program that will work in 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2013

Hi I'm doing some `C#` codes in my `VS 2013` at my own pc but it doesn't work on our school's pc because the version of the Visual Studio there is very outdated , it was only 2008.

And I cant run my code that I've been working in 2008 that was made in 2013.

So How can i run it? Should I download `VS 2008` ?

thank you

Comment: Thats an open ended question - if your teacher needs to be able to look at it and show it compiles and runs etc.. yes you would

Comment: That's just a tad too old. Check this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/03/28/round-tripping-with-visual-studio-11.aspx) about VS 11 (which was released as VS2012), where they started making strides in round-tripping between 2010 and 2012.

Comment: Title looks like you are going to travel back in time. ^.^

Answer (score 1):

It is probably the Project and solution files that are causing you problems, as these change from version to version. C# itself though hasn't changed so much.

You could perhaps consider just copying the c-sharp files between the computers.
ie, have a skeleton solution in each version and copy and past the CS files, or the text from the files into the projects.

Bear in mind that Visual Studio 2008 is going to target .Net Framework 3.5, so just avoid using any later framework functionality (which shouldn't be too hard).